# Parse schema add field if not existent

Tags: parse-platform

In our code we have an init function, which creates all the schemes, sets up the ACL...

How am I supposed to handle changes in the schemas(For example when adding a new field for an schema, or changing the CLP). My primitive approach was to just set all the attributes and call update. This throws an exception saying "Field name exists, cannot update".

My goal would be to just call update if there are changes it applies them otherwise, it just does nothing.

Any hint how to achieve this? Or is this in general the wrong approach?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to update ?

Comment: My goal is to automatically update the db if we decide we need more columns. I don't want to write an upgrade db method which gets only the changed fields as this is hard to maintain. I just want to set columns that should be there and parse figures out itself which are already existent